# ResourceDictionary creation through code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a WPF User Control project and I'm trying to create Resource Dictionary using the following code

```
var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("/SampleExtension;component/MyResource.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Above code throws a NotSupportedException with the message *"The URI prefix is not recognized"*. Btw MyResource.xaml's build action is set to Resource.

Similar URI when used from XAML works perfectly.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/SampleExtension;component/MyResource.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <my:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

What am I doing incorrectly in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my project was an User Control project (and a WPF Application was not running when I tested above code), I will have to reference Application class.

```
var app = Application.Current;
var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
resourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("/SampleExtension;component/MyResource.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Something similar has been explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710776/pack-urls-and-unit-testing-problem-with-my-environment)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing authority path.
It should be;

```
 "pack://application:,,,/SampleExtension;component/MyResource.xaml"
```

For your reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this help.

Comment: I've added a comment as a separate answer as the formatting was lost here....

Answer (score 0):

From HungDL's link it also states:

From that same link:

> A fully qualified pack URI includes the scheme, the authority, and the
> path, and it is considered an absolute pack URI. As a simplification
> for developers, XAML elements typically allow you to set appropriate
> attributes with a relative pack URI, which includes only the path.
>
> For example, consider the following absolute pack URI for a resource
> file in the local assembly.
>
> pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.xaml
>
> The relative pack URI that refers to this resource file would be the
> following.
>
> /ResourceFile.xaml